# reactive form does not work in MatDialogRef

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, mat-dialog

I'm facing a weird issue, I can't get my reactive form work with validations like .invalid  .dirty & .touched.

My form is in a MatDialog component and his component look like :

```
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { LogementReservation } from '../../models/logementReservation';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-popup-reservation-logement',
  templateUrl: './popup-reservation-logement.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./popup-reservation-logement.component.scss']
})
export class PopupReservationLogementComponent implements OnInit{

  form!: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<PopupReservationLogementComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public logementReservation: LogementReservation,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateDebut: this.logementReservation.dateDebut,
      dateFin: this.logementReservation.dateFin,
      emailDemandeur: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      prix: this.logementReservation.prix,
      message: '',
      annonceur: this.logementReservation.annonceur,
      logementId: this.logementReservation.logementId
    });
  }

  cancel(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  submit() {
    this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
  }

}
```

I open it with :

```
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopupReservationLogementComponent, {
      width: '450px',
      data: logementReservation,
    });
```

In the MatDialog, html look like :

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
  <div mat-dialog-content fxLayout="column">
    <p>Réservation du {{ logementReservation.dateDebut }} au {{ logementReservation.dateFin }}</p>
    <p>Prix : {{ logementReservation.prix }}€</p>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Votre email *</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="emailDemandeur">
      <pre>{{ form.get('emailDemandeur') | json }} affichage</pre>
      <div class="control" 
      *ngIf="form.get('emailDemandeur')!.invalid && (form.get('emaemailDemandeuril')!.dirty || form.get('emailDemandeur')!.touched)">
        adresse invalide.
    </div>
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Message (facultatif):</mat-label>
      <textarea matInput formControlName="message" rows="4"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button (click)="cancel()">Annuler</button>
    <button mat-button [disabled]="form.invalid" type="submit" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

As you can notice, I tried to investigate by displaying "form.get('emailDemandeur')" but in console, I can see:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'yf'
    |     property 'controls' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'dateDebut' -> object with constructor 'wf'
    --- property '_parent' closes the circle
```

I have an other MatDialog with only one String and implement the same way and all work as expected.

If anybody see what's wrong, thank to point me out what is my mistake

Comment: please remove this <pre>{{ form.get('emailDemandeur') | json }} affichage</pre> and check

Comment: @cfprabhu Following your recommandation, I get: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'dirty'). So I removed "&& (form.get('emaemailDemandeuril')!.dirty || form.get('emailDemandeur')!.touched)" and all work so it's nice but I'd like the message "adresse invalide" display only if my form is writing and for now it's displaying from the begining. But anyway, thank you to advise me this, it's better than before :)

Answer (score 0):

Hum ok, I'm such an idiot, I wrote with copy past : form.get('emaemailDemandeuril') instead of form.get('emailDemandeur')